# Pandas group values and get their average

Tags: python, pandas

So my df looks something like this:

```
    Model       Price
   1 Series     £42000
   1 Series     £45000
   2 Series     £32000 
   2 Series     £25000
```

I would like to get the mean price for each model, and map that as a bar chart. I have tried df.groupby(['Model','MSRP']).mean(); however, that does not display the average price for each model, it just groups it looking something like this:

```
   Model        Price
   1 Series     £42000
                £45000
   2 Series     £32000
                £25000
```

Comment: You need to groupby `Model` only so `Price` is not part of the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `lstrip` `£`, cast to integer, and then  compute the [`GroupBy.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) and plot:

```
df.Price.str.lstrip('£').astype(int).groupby(df.Model).mean().plot.barh()
```

[image]

Comment: Or just `df["Price"].str[1:].astype...`